# mysqlで2つのテーブルから紐付いていないデータも取得する

Tags: mysql

下記のような2つのテーブルからデータを取得する時にテンプレートに紐付いているカテゴリーが1つも存在しないカテゴリーデータも取得したいのですがどのようにすればいいのでしょうか？
できれば1回のクエリで取得したいと考えています。

○カテゴリーtbl
id| カテゴリー名|削除フラグ
1 | カテゴリー1 |0
2 | カテゴリー2 |0
3 | カテゴリー3 |0

○テンプレートtbl
id| カテゴリーid| テンプレート名| 削除フラグ
1 | 1          | テンプレート1 |0
2 | 1          | テンプレート2 |0
3 | 2          | テンプレート3 |0
4 | 2          | テンプレート3 |1

---

■理想の取得データ
テンプレートid| カテゴリーid |テンプレート名
1           | 1           |テンプレート1
2           | 1           |テンプレート2
3           | 2           |テンプレート3
NULL        | 3           |NULL

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: LEFT JOINで検索しましょう

Comment: ありがとうございます。先ほど追記させて頂いたのですが、各テーブルに削除フラグを付けた場合はどのような条件で検索すればよろしいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

テーブルを作ります。

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categor_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `template` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `template_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

データをインサートします。

```
INSERT INTO `category` (`id`,`categor_name`) VALUES (1,'カテゴリー1');
INSERT INTO `category` (`id`,`categor_name`) VALUES (2,'カテゴリー2');
INSERT INTO `category` (`id`,`categor_name`) VALUES (3,'カテゴリー3');

INSERT INTO `template` (`id`,`category_id`,`template_name`) VALUES (1,1,'テンプレート1');
INSERT INTO `template` (`id`,`category_id`,`template_name`) VALUES (2,1,'テンプレート2');
INSERT INTO `template` (`id`,`category_id`,`template_name`) VALUES (3,2,'テンプレート3');
```

検索文は下記の通りです。

```
SELECT 
    template.id,
    category.id,
    template_name
FROM
    category
        LEFT JOIN
    template ON category.id = template.category_id
```

[LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)についてここに参照してください。

Comment: わざわざご丁寧にありがとうございます。こちらですが、削除フラグを各テーブルに付けた場合はどうなりますでしょうか？

Comment: SELECT 
        template.id, category.id, template_name
    FROM
        category
            LEFT JOIN
        template ON category.id = template.category_id
            AND template.delete_flag = 0
    WHERE
        category.delete_flag = 0    削除フラグのコラム名はdelete_flagだとしますと、検索文は上記になります。

Comment: なるほど。 結合キーを複数にするということですね。
勉強になりました。
ありがとうございます。